# Postgres: count unique array entries from subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, aggregate-functions

If my subquery foo liberates the rows:-

```
ID, USERS 
1   {23129}
2   {23142}
3   {23300,23300}
4   {23129,23300}
```

How can I get a count of unique users in a query using a window function such as:-

```
SELECT ... FROM ( <subquery> ) FOO
```

I tried this:-

```
array_length(array_agg(array_length(array(SELECT Distinct unnest(users))),1)) over(), 1)
```

But get the error that the array dimensions are not the same

NOTE WELL: I cannot change the subquery to solve this problem.

I can get the IDs in an array as follows:-

```
string_to_array(string_agg(array_to_string(user_ids, ','), ',') over(),',')
```

But they are not distinct.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, problem is the subquery cannot be changed.

Comment: `SELECT count(distinct BAR) FROM ( <subquery> ) FOO, unnest(FOO.USERS) AS BAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a known alghoritm in a simple SQL function:

```
create or replace function array_unique_elements(arr anyarray)
    returns integer
    language sql immutable
as $$
    select count(distinct a)::int
    from unnest(arr) a 
$$;
```

Use:

```
select *, array_unique_elements(users)
from (
    values
    (1, '{23129}'::int[]),
    (2, '{23142}'),
    (3, '{23300,23300}'),
    (4, '{23129,23300}')
) foo (id, users)

 id |     users     | array_unique_elements 
----+---------------+-----------------------
  1 | {23129}       |                     1
  2 | {23142}       |                     1
  3 | {23300,23300} |                     1
  4 | {23129,23300} |                     2
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're overcomplicating things - you can unnest the array, and then query a distinct count from it:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u)
FROM   (SELECT UNNEST(users) AS u
        FROM   mytable) t
```

Comment: Thank but the subquery cannot be changed

Answer (score -1):

I would as well just count distinct as Mureinik suggests.

And regarding error that you get - here's tight syntax example with `array_length`:

```
t=# with a(v) as (values('{1,2}'::int[]),('{2,3}')) 
select array_length(array_agg(distinct unnest),1) from (
  select unnest(v) from a
) a;
 array_length
--------------
            3
(1 row)
```

Of course it **WILL NOT** with window aggregation - only with `GROUP BY`